# Can someone explain this kinematics problem to me?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

[image]

This is the problem itself. It is from David Morin's Introductory Mechanics.

[image]

This is the solution to the problem (or part of it)

Comment: Please spare time to read this before you post any question next time. [1. MathJax tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference&ved=2ahUKEwia5uuh29DpAhVDwTgGHVi6DwAQFjAAegQIBBAC&usg=AOvVaw1zLdIXv6Cu4GY53kDgHoTt). [2. How do I ask homework question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange). [3. How to ask a good question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

$U\sin\phi /g$ is just the time to highest point of a ball thrown.

We are talking about the box .

$Mg\sin\beta$ is the force along, down the incline . 
So $g\sin\beta$ is the acceleration along it.

Then from $a=(v-u)/t$

We get the result.

Read question carefully.
We are talking about meeting at maximum height of block/box not ball.

Comment: Thank you! I think that was my mistake